# Openstack, make my insstance acessible from different machine

Tags: openstack, devstack

How to make my instance accessible from another machine in the same network, I've already asssign a floating IP?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have assigned FIP, 
1. verify you have ingress/egress allow on CIDR 0.0.0.0/0 rules configured on security-group.
2. Ping from other machine which is in same network as FIP.

If step 2 succeeds, then you should be able to access VM over network.

In case if step 2 fails, check below things.

1. Run neutron floatingip-list and check if you have FIP configured for Instance
2. Go to to nova-api and check logs for clue